# Exceptions package location in Java

Tags: java, exception

Why some exceptions are located in their respective packages (like `IOException`, located in `java.io`) but others are in `java.lang` (like `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` in `java.lang`). Is this because one is checked and other is Unchecked Exception?

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException **isn't** "in `java.lang.Throwable`".

Comment: @immibis Yes it is, at least the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) seems to imply so.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Where does it say that?

Comment: @immibis Maybe my terminology is off.  `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` descends from `Throwable` ... perhaps the OP also has this misconception.

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException does indeed descend from or inherit from Throwable. However the OP says it is *in* Throwable. Do you see the difference between "descends from" and "is inside"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't think that base on checked and unchecked conditions java exceptions are located in respective packages.If we consider about java.io package and java.lang packages,
   java.io package contains classes for system input and output through data streams, serialization and the file system.And also handling files also done by Java I/O API.

---

java.lan package contains all the classes that are using to the design of the Java programming language such as String, Math. And provide  basic runtime support for threads and processes.

Java IOException is thrown whenever an input or output stream is interrupted.So this regarding System input and output.So this IOException class must come under java.io package.

Java RuntimeExceptions such as ArrayIndexOutOfBoundEceptions are checked at the runtime.java.lan package support to handle runtime threads.It's include classes that support runtime for threads and process.

So IOException,ArrayIndexOutOfBound are classes with relevant function.So those classes must be categorized under relevant packages.

Answer (score 1):

First: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is **not** inside `java.lang.Throwable`. It is inside the package `java.lang`. It is a subclass of `java.lang.Throwable`, but so are all exceptions (including `IOException`).

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is inside `java.lang` because all the "basic stuff related to the core language" is in `java.lang`, and `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is "basic stuff related to the core language".

`IOException` is inside `java.io` because all the stuff related to I/O is in `java.io`, and `IOException` is "stuff related to I/O".

There is no deep or interesting technical reason.

Comment: are you the immibis as in, forcefields, microblocks, dimensional anchors, peripherals, etc? I haven't seen that name in years, lol

Comment: @forresthopkinsa ...yes

Comment: that's pretty funny, I'm a little surprised I recognized your name

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, it is a good idea to place *checked* exceptions near the code which is throwing those types of exceptions.  This explains your first observation.  On the other hand, the exception `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` is an *unchecked* runtime exception.  It is associated with a type of runtime error from which the program is generally not expected to recover.  As such, it placed in `java.lang.throwable` with other similar runtime exceptions.  So as a general rule, if you define custom exceptions for your program, you should therefore probably put them in the packages, or near the code, which uses them.

Comment: "So as a general rule, if you define custom exceptions for your program, they are probably checked"... I disagree.  Checked exceptions have more or less fallen out of favor (they were thought to be a good idea at the time but have caused problems).  I think that's still controversial.  However, most of the new custom exceptions we define extend `RuntimeException`, so they're unchecked.  But we put them in the package related to what they're used for.

Comment: @ajb I think custom exceptions is not related to this. Custom exceptions will lie in our own packages. We cannot do much about that. Tim, thanks for the answer.